# multiple values in single parameter with one request is not parsing

Tags: jmeter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46f4r.png)After recording the form submission with blazemeter, collected multiple values in a single parameter in the HTTP request but when executing the test it is failing.
I modified the parameters into single values then it is started working. Please help me how can I pass this test with multiple values